# jQuery check if has class and add css

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Im writing a jquery script that checks if the modal has popped out and adds a css to a class so that the fixed navbar won't block the called modal.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 if ($('#myModal').hasClass('in'))  {
     $(".cbp-af-header").css("z-index", "0 !important");  
 } 
  else { 
     $(".cbp-af-header").css("z-index", "10000 !important");  
  }

});
```

Doesn't seem to work. Any help?

Comment: where is cbp-af-header in relation to id myModal? Could you include the html and any css relevant to the question?

Comment: There isnt a problem in you jquery code itself, put that code in a callback for when the modal is opened

Comment: depperm, cbp-af-header is a fixed-to-top header that blocks the model whenever it pops in. It has the z-index of 10000. So what I want to achieve, is when it is visible, it will add a css for the header z-index 0.

AmmarCSE, I'm looking up modal callbacks right now. Thanks for your tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is bootstrap modal better you use the modal shown and hidden events of it

```
$("#myModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function(){
   $(".cbp-af-header").css("z-index", "0 !important");
});
$("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
   $(".cbp-af-header").css("z-index", "10000 !important");
});
```